# what is the best practice concerning opening CSV files in python

Tags: python, beginner, datetime, csv

I am looking for the best way to save regular data from a series of sensors to a CSV file.
the program will be reading every sensor once a minute 24/7 and needs to report the results to a CSV file that can be accessed at anytime via ftp..
I also wish to create a new file each day.

Is it best to;

A: open the file at midnight, and keep it open for 24 hours as I append to it every minute, then close it at the end of the day?

B: open and close the file every hour, to save an updated copy to the hard disk? in case of a crash.

C: open and close it every minute, only long enough to add the new line of data?

or is there a better practice to consider.

my current code:

```py
def writeData:
    today = date.today()
    today = date.strftime("%b-%d-%Y")
    fileName = "Sensor Log {}".format(today)
    with open(fileName, mode='w') as logFile:
    logFile = csv.writer(logFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    time = datetime.now()
    logFile.writerow(['Time','Date', 'Sensor01', 'Sensor02'])
    logFile.writerow([time, date, sen01, sen02])
```

Comment: `def writeData:` that's not valid syntax.

Comment: Unfortunately your question is currently off-topic. We only review [code that works as intended](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3650). [Generic best practice questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3652) cannot be reasonably answered. Once you [edit] your post to fix the issues we'll be happy to review your code.

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer to your question will depend largely on the operating environment of your Python program.

The actual language (Python) is not really relevant here, as it does nothing special in this regard.
File management is the responsibility of the OS, and Python, like most programming languages only provides an interface to the underlying OS APIs.

Generally speaking, "once a minute" is long enough interval on any modern system, including SBCs like Raspbery Pi, to justify "open -> append -> close" method.

This will ensure that:

A) The file is always as up to date as possible and ready for download.
B) If there is a software crash, power loss, or other indecent, as little data as possible is lost.

Also, one thing to note is that while on Linux based OS (or BSD based), a file can be simultaneously accessed for reading an writing by different processes, on Windows keeping the file open for writing may render it inaccessible for download over FTP.

Of course, if your system has some particular constraints about storage, for example an extremely slow or extremely busy persistent storage, then reducing the number of access operations may be a good idea.

Also, in the unlikely case appending data is problematic (like if you were writing to tape storage), waiting until the daily file is collected in RAM would be a requirement.

All that said, your current code has some issues:

First, you are using `strftime` incorrectly, it must be called on the actual object holding a specific date, not on the `date` class.
I also recommend avoiding spaces in file names as they can cause issues with some tools

```
fileName = "sensor_log_{}.csv".format(date.today().strftime("%b-%d-%Y"))
```

Second, your actual write code always clobbers the content of the file with a single line of actual data.

You should write the column titles only once when creating a new file for the current day, and then use "append" mode each time you write a single sensor reading:

```
with open(fileName, mode='a', newline='') as logFile:
    logFile = csv.writer(logFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    time = datetime.now()

    # you are missing code to crate date and time string:
    st_time = time.strftime("HH:mm")
    st_date = time.strftime("%b-%d-%Y")

    logFile.writerow([st_time, st_date, sen01, sen02])
```

Also, you may want to consider dropping the date column completely if you are going to have a new file for every day with the date already in its name.

This will reduce file size.

If you choose to keep it, for esthetics mostly, it is common to make the date column the first column, and then the time and everything else.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, and excellent answer. The question itself is off-topic because the code is incorrect and doesn't work. It will probably be closed and then only you, the person that asked the question and users that have more than 10,000 reputation will be able to see it so you won't get many reputation points. It is best not to answer off-topic questions. You can learn what makes a question off-topic in our [guidelines for asking](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking).